# How to put three dots at the end of the StackPanel that will say there are more items

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I would like a **behavior** like in `TextBlock` that can be given `TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"` and then I will get three dots.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" MaxWidth="150">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat='{}{0}\, '}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <DockPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

```
public ObservableCollection<string> MyList { get; set; } = new() {"AAAAAA", "BBBBBB", "CCCCCC", "DDDDDD" };
```

And that's my result, but not the result I wanted

[image]

Comment: Why are you using an `ItemsControl` with a `DockPanel` if you want to display a `string`?

Comment: Because I did it for the example, in my case it's some object that I end up wanting to display its name, which is a string type

Comment: The solution would still be the same, i.e. add a `string` property to the view model and bind a `TextBlock` to this one. Using an `ItemsControl` to to displayed a trimmed `string` is not a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `ItemsControl` and use a `TextBlock` that binds to a source property that returns the value of `string.Join(", ", MyList)`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding StringProperty}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
```

It doesn't make much sense to try to implement this using an `ItemsControl` in the view.